# javascript window redirect doesn't fire up

Tags: javascript, webforms

This problem seems to be odd to me and I can't seem to fix it.  I do have a simple HTML form; inside, I do have a textbox and a button as shown down here:

```
<form id="form1" method="get"> <!-- Note: No Action property -->
    <div>
       <h1>
           Simple Test Form</h1>
       <table border="0" width="400">
           <tr>
               <td align="right">
                   All of these words
               </td>
               <td>
                   <input name="txtAll" id="txtAll" type="text" value="testing keyword" />
               </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td colspan="2" align="center">
                   <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" onclick="myJS(this);" />
               </td>
           </tr>
       </table>
   </div>
</form>
```

MyJS file is as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myJS(which) {
        var CONSTANT_SITE_TARGET = "http://servername/redirect/target.aspx?text=";

        //capture all values from the form
        var allWords = document.getElementById("txtAll").value;

        var morestring = ""; //More data manipulation here.....
        var url = CONSTANT_SITE_TARGET + allWords + morestring;

        window.open(url);
        //window.location = url;          //Doesn't work
        //window.location.href = url;     //Doesn't work
        //self.location = url;            //Doesn't work
        //top.location = url;             //Doesn't work
    }
</script>
```

As you can see, it doesn't redirect to the designated URL in the javascript.  When I use the window.open then it works. Note that in the < form... > tag, I don't put the *action* property in it.  I don't want to open a new browser, just redirect to the new url within the same browser.

Is there a way to redirect it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here

```
function myJS(which) {
    var CONSTANT_SITE_TARGET = "http://servername/redirect/target.aspx?text=";

    //capture all values from the form
    var allWords = which.txtAll.value;

    var morestring = ""; //More data manipulation here.....
    return CONSTANT_SITE_TARGET + allWords + morestring;
}


<form id="form1" method="get" onsubmit="this.action=myJs(this)">
<div>
    <h1>
        Simple Test Form</h1>
    <table border="0" width="400">
        <tr>
            <td align="right">
                All of these words
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="txtAll" id="txtAll" type="text" value="testing keyword" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center">
                <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</form>
```

to elaborate on a comment:

```
<script>
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("Submit").onclick=function() {
     var CONSTANT_SITE_TARGET = "http://servername/redirect/target.aspx?text=";
    //capture all values from the form
    var allWords = document.getElementById("txtAll".value;
    var morestring = ""; //More data manipulation here.....
    location = CONSTANT_SITE_TARGET + allWords + morestring;
  }
}
</script>
<div>
    <h1>
        Simple Test Form</h1>
    <table border="0" width="400">
        <tr>
            <td align="right">
                All of these words
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="txtAll" id="txtAll" type="text" value="testing keyword" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center">
                <input type="button" id="Submit" value="Submit" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: If all you're trying to do is redirect the page when the button is clicked, there's NO reason for a form and your complicated Javascript to redirect. Make your input button type="button", onclick="myJS();", and in your function get the textbox element by ID, get its value, and redirect the browser with: window.location.href = whatever;

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the form tags. Or, set the "type" attribute of your button to be "button", not "submit". The form submits when you click the button, but you don't want that to happen. Either removing the form or changing the button should fix improper redirection. When you don't specify an action, I'm pretty sure the default is the current URL.

Comment: And add a window name to be compatible - window.open(url,"_blank") or if you want the same window, `location=url`

Answer (score 1):

Ok, just an idea. As you haven't set the `action` parameter, the default behaviour of a `submit` button is to reload the same page. You alter that behaviour by handling its `onclick`. Maybe there is a conflict that can be resolved by having `return false;` at the end of the click handler, which prevents the default action for that event.

Comment: the default action isn't to reload the same page, it's to submit the form to the same URL. reloading and submitting are completely different things. and putting return false; at the end of a submit button is pointless - use type="button" instead

Answer (score -1):

Try one the options for redirection below. I commented out three of them so that the code stays valid, but you may play around with either and see if it suits your needs.

```
    var CONSTANT_SITE_TARGET = "http://servername/redirect/target.aspx?text=";

    //capture all values from the form
    var allWords = document.getElementById("txtAll").value;

    var morestring = ""; //More data manipulation here.....
    var url = CONSTANT_SITE_TARGET + allWords + morestring;

     window.location.href= url;
     //window.navigate(url);
     //self.location(url);
     //top.location(url);
```